# Result is not saved in json

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using `scrapy` and running this script:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import SizeerItem
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class SizeerSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sizeer'
    pg = 0
    currentPg = 2
    start_urls = [
        'https://sizeer.lt/moterims'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = SizeerItem()
        pages = response.xpath("//nav[@class='m-pagination']//span[3]/text()").extract()
        pages = list(dict.fromkeys(pages))

        if self.pg == 0:
            pages = list(int(s) for s in pages[0].split() if s.isdigit())
            self.pg = pages[0]

        name = response.xpath("//div[@class='b-productList_content']//a/@href").extract()

        items['name'] = list(dict.fromkeys(name))

        while self.currentPg <= self.pg:
            url = response.request.url + "?sort=default&limit=60&page=" + str(self.currentPg)
            self.currentPg += 1
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

This way:

```
scrapy crawl sizeer -s FEED_URI='mydata.json' -s FEED_FORMAT=json
```

But after that my `mydata.json` is empty. This is my first time trying to 'play' with it and can't really understand where is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to `yield` the items you scrape so Scrapy Engine will run them through the pipelines and thorugh the [Feed Export](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) (which is what you need to export to the file).

Since `yield` is non-blocking you can add just after populating it and the function will still `yield` your requests after:

```
    ...
    name = response.xpath("//div[@class='b-productList_content']//a/@href").extract()
    items['name'] = list(dict.fromkeys(name))
    yield items  # <<< Here for example 

    while self.currentPg <= self.pg:
        ...
```

As @yordan pointed out, you can simplify the way you are executing the spider like this: (However it's not the solution to the problem)

```
scrapy crawl sizeer -o mydata.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
[Scrapy use item and save data in a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56005678/scrapy-use-item-and-save-data-in-a-json-file)

Pay attention to the yielding and the calling of the spider.

Comment: A link to support your answer is most welcome; but merely a link to documentation does not suffice for an answer on Stack Overflow.